# How to allow Client Tenants to add custom roles in my multi tenant Azure AD app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have multi tenant application that has default app roles configured in the manifest of the source tenant and these roles are working perfectly fine in the clients Azure AD tenants. The problem is that I can't find a way to allow the clients to modify the manifest of the app in their tenant as the app doesn't pop-up in their App Registration list (only in the Enterprise Applications). Do I need to make my app gallery app or there is other way to make this work.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi，do you have time to research my answer? Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can edit the application manifest by creating an **app gallery app**.

However, there is one thing you should pay attention to. After being created in this way, may change the properties of the application. It is not a multi-tenant application, but the functions they implement are still the same.

Comment: Thank you Carl.
So the only way to allow clients (other tenants) to modify the manifest in order to add custom roles is to make my app gallery app? I thought that there is a way to provide the same functionality with non-gallery app?

Comment: @I_do_this_for_Aiur  Hi, I have not tried other methods, but I believe that editing the application manifest by creating an app gallery app is a very good method.